# Someone repeatedly answers Facetime from another device when I am called

Tags: iphone, facetime

There are no other devices but my iPhone on my account. I have changed my Apple ID password multiple times and it continues to happen. Same person every time. What do I do?

Comment: how do you check that there are no other devices on your account?

Comment: When you say "someone" and that it is the same person every time, are you saying that an actual person answers, you know what his voice sounds like, etc.? Maybe you could contact them to solve this issue if their intent is not malicious... Meanwhile you should check the trusted and contact phone numbers for your iCloud account.